# Problem editing document set in SharePoint

Tags: 2010, document-set

I want to customize the edit form for document sets. I know that it uses editform.aspx. I create jQuery code inside content editor web part.  When I edit document sets attribute, it works with content type document, but not with my document set. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is , the document content type columns must be the same as your document set content type columns & you can hide or show column by using jquery..